# How can I correct my method so that it removes string from array?

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to create a method that searches through the 'data' array to find the parameter 'elt'.  If it exists, the method deletes it.  I cannot figure out how to delete the string "elt".  Below is what I have so far.

```
public class Bag<T> implements Iterable<T> {

private final int MAXLEN = 3;
private int size;
private T[] data; // array

public T remove(T elt) {

    for (T word : data) {
        if (word == "elt")
            data = data.remove(word);
        }
    }       
}
```

The error I get is "Cannot remove(T) on the array type T[].

Can someone tell me how I can properly remove the string "elt" from the array?

Comment: Arrays are fixed size so you'd need to re-create one and fill the content into it. You can look at `System.arraycopy`, for instance. Also don't compare String's content with `==`, use `equals`.

Comment: .. or simply use an `ArrayList`...

Comment: this looks like an implementation of an `ArrayList`. If you want to remove an element from an array, you'll have to shift all elements with higher index one index down. And: comparison of strings is done via `someString.equals(otherString)`. `==` should only be used for primitive types

Comment: Thanks for the help!  Down voter, can you please explain why you down voted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`data` is an array so you cannot remove it in the sense you are trying to do.

You have a few options:

1. Set the element to null
2. (1) and move the other elements down
3. Use a `Collection` (such as `ArrayList`) - then you can remove as you'd like

Option (3) would be the simplest. If you are required to use an array, (1) would look something like:

```
for (int i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
    if ("elt".equals(data[i]) {
        data[i] = null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't "remove" a value from an array: you cannot change the number of elements in the array once it has been created.

You can, however, change the value of an element, e.g. setting it to `null`. In order to do this, you'd need the index of the element, so you can't use an enhanced for loop.

If you want a variable-size container, use a mutable `List`, e.g. `ArrayList`. You could then simply use `list.remove("elt")`, no explicit loop required.

Aside: use `"elt".equals(word)` instead of `word == "elt"`.